# How to reverse engineer simple usb device [windows -> linux]

Tags: windows, linux, usb

I'd like to reverse engineer my usb beer-can refrigurator, which does connect via USB on windows and via simple GUI tray-tool can set/query temperature.

I was thinking about running virtualboxed driver and capturing usb communications via wireshark and usbmon interface.

Anyone know of handy guide/tools that would help me reverse engineer this and possibly write simple userspace tool / driver?

Comment: It's not quite the same as your question, but you may want to look at http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1786/usb-dongle-traffic-monitoring

Answer (score 28):

VMWare can capture USB traffic between the device and the VM. A VMWare engineer even made an open-source tool for analyzing and visualizing USB logs - Virtual USB analyzer.

[image]

- [Web site](http://vusb-analyzer.sourceforge.net/)
- [Tutorial](http://vusb-analyzer.sourceforge.net/tutorial.html)

Alternatively, a tool for converting VMWare logs to .pcap for analyzing in Wireshark is available [from Sogeti](http://esec-lab.sogeti.com/post/2011/04/06/Sniffing-USB-traffic-with-VMWare).

Answer (score 19):

Matt Cutts wrote a series of blog posts outlining the general approach of reverse-engineering a USB device and getting it working with linux, and explaining how he did this for a USB controlled toy missile launcher. You may find them a useful starting point.

- http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/reverse-engineering-a-windows-usb-driver/
- http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/playing-with-a-usb-missile-launcher/
- http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/linux-usb-device-driver-info/
- http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/compile-a-simple-usb-program-in-linux/